# Blender won't open. The command window flashes but nothing else. I want to share my solution

Tags: blend-files, installation, windows

Problem: Blender worked until I installed 2.90. It opened once then failed afterwards. When I tried to open Blender, the command prompt flashed and disappeared. Blender would not open.  I don't like running Blender on the laptop display because the ergonomics and the screen size is too small for mesh work, so I use large 27" external monitors.

My setup:
Windows 10 Home 64
Dell G3 3779

- BIOS: 1.13.0 (type: UEFI)
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz (12 CPUs), ~2.2GHz
- Memory: 8192MB RAM
- Available OS Memory: 8052MB RAM
- Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 with Max-Q Design
  Display Memory: 10077 MB
  Dedicated Memory: 6052 MB
  Shared Memory: 4025 MB
- 2 - 27" monitors
- StarTech.com USB 3.0 to Dual HDMI Adapter - 4K 30Hz - External Video & Graphics Card - Dual Monitor Display Adapter

I tried running debug commands and ran through many of the solutions offered here but nothing resolved my issue.

Solution:

- Through a process of trial and error. (shutdown/restart) I removed the Star Tech USB dual HDMI adaptor and found that all versions of Blender WILL work on the laptop alone.
- I then plugged in 1 monitor directly into the HDMI port on the laptop and all versions of Blender work. (At least I can use one large monitor!)
- I then reconnected the StarTech USB dual HDMI adaptor and tried to open Blender.  Blender failed to open.
- I removed the Startech USB adaptor and went back to ONE direct HDMI connection and the Blender works with the external monitor.

So, for whatever reason, Blender will not work when using the Dual HDMI adaptor.

Comment: Hello and welcome While answering your own questions is possible and encouraged do so using the answer section below. Please edit your question and remove the answer part, and pasting in an actual answer.

Comment: Don't make the answer part of the question. Use the answsers section for that read: [Can I answer my own question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I face the same problem with my USB docking station. Interestingly, it works with one notebook but not with the other. There seems to be another factor in the background controlling whether it works or not...